# hibernate: Couldn't connect to DB from eclipse

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I get the following output when I'm trying to run `hibernate` in eclipse:

```
INFO: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml`enter code here`
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:1402)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1424)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1411)
    at Str.ClientProgram.main(ClientProgram.java:12)
```

Does anyone know what may cause this behaviour?

Comment: how you are configuring hibernate?

Comment: Where is the `hibernate.cfg.xml` located in your project?

Comment: I improved the title and the whole formulation of the question. Added the 'java' tag, too.